# Spring Boot and Logging with External Tomcat only outputs startup log

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

My Spring boot 2 app is not showing any log message when is running. I can only see the startup log. This app is deployed as WAR in the production server and I configured the log to output to a file:

```
logging.file = app.log
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.pattern.console= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
```

In my local I can see whatever debug message I include in my code but in the server I can't. I only see the application startup trace.

My config to generate the file is the provided by official guideance. And the tomcat dependency in the app.war:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Do you have any idea of what is happening? It is strange. The log file is generating in the server ( we deploy it in a docker container ) but after the app is running, no more log is output to the file.

Comment: did you check the file you are writing has permission to write by tomcat?

Comment: The file is generated in the tomcat folder with this permissions -rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 143674 Sep 21 18:44 app.log

Is it necessary to include the "Setting up servlet" step of this tutorial? https://stormpath.com/blog/tutorial-spring-boot-war-files#setting-up-a-servlet

Comment: can you check you are getting info and error logs in file..try to throw somthing

Comment: I don't get any error. In fact, there is a process which throws it (it returns me 500 in the browser) but I don't see anything

Comment: Can you please  see my answer and crate logback xml

Comment: I am using Spring boot default logging. Why do I need logback? @kj007

Comment: @mannuk Did you get this working. I'm facing a similar problem. Application logs are present only for the startup but nothing gets logged once startup is finished.

Answer (score 0):

By default Spring Boot logs on INFO level, which should include ERROR.

As per Spring boot logging guide [79.1.1 Configure Logback for File-only Output](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html)

If you want to disable console logging and write output only to a file, you need a custom `logback-spring.xml` that imports `file-appender.xml` but not `console-appender.xml`, as shown in the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

You also need to add `logging.file` to your application.properties which you have alraedy added.

Comment: I don't want to disable console logging. I want to see the logging in the file in production in my app.log but I can't see more than the startup log.